# Broken and missing prongs from usb ports

Tags: usb

can i get replacement slots that fit in usb ports the prongs are bent and unworking on 1 port and the other came out when charging a device in port.When trying to retrieve it. the pronged plastic piece snapped.Can it be repaired? Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. The ports are one solid (or not-so-solid in your case) piece and are soldered to the PCB and are therefore not easy to replace.

Comment: Somebody who has a replacement part (i.e. broken motherboard of same make/model) could desolder the socket and solder a new one.  It is likely going to cost more to pay someone to do that than replace the motherboard, though.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a PCI, or PCIe-1x (whichever one you have available) USB card and use that.. tape off your broken ports or fill them with hot-glue because if the little wire prongs in there touch they can short-out and cause damage to your motherboard